# Update with Subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try update postgresql table using subquery

```
        UPDATE
            bc
        SET
            (r, w) = ($1, $2)
        WHERE
            bc.sr_id IN (
                UPDATE
                    sr
                SET
                    (r, w) = ($1, $2)
                WHERE
                    si = $3 AND
                    rti = $4 AND
                    fc = $5
                RETURNING sr.id
            )
```

Why it's returns error?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You can't chain DML statements like that. You will have to use a writable CTE.

```
WITH buz AS
(UPDATE foo
SET num=0 WHERE num>5 RETURNING num)
UPDATE bar SET num=0 WHERE num IN
(SELECT num FROM foo);
SELECT * FROM foo;
SELECT * FROM bar;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/513a2/1

Comment: Available as of version 9.1 and a reason to upgrade if you're using an older version.